# \cline Not Working with Customized Column Padding

Tags: tables, rules

When I reduce the table's horizontal padding using `@{}`, the `\cline` command does not work properly anymore. It is shown in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Text & Text & Text \\ \cline{2-3}
Text & Text & Text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{|@{\hspace{1mm}}c@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}c@{\hspace{1mm}}|@{\hspace{1mm}}c@{\hspace{1mm}}|}
\hline
Text & Text & Text \\ \cline{2-3}
Text & Text & Text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of specifying (half the) intercolumn whitespace by hand in each and every case, you may want to simply redefine the parameter `\tabcolsep`. That way, the issue with the misaligned `\cline` will take care of itself automatically, and I dare say the code becomes a lot more readable to boot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|@{\hspace{1mm}}c@{\hspace{1mm}}|
                 @{\hspace{1mm}}c@{\hspace{1mm}}|
                 @{\hspace{1mm}}c@{\hspace{1mm}}|}
\hline
Text & Text & Text \\ \cline{2-3}
Text & Text & Text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\smallskip 
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Text & Text & Text \\ \cline{2-3}
Text & Text & Text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```